# Single word or short phrase for giving a passing mark?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> I thanked my teacher for **giving me a pass mark** in the exam.

Is there a single word or short phrase for the emphasised phrase?

Comment: *Passing* me is common. A word particular to you/me... harder, if at all.

Comment: Do you really want to restrict the possible answers to a single word that can be used as a direct replacement for the phrase?

Comment: Hm, phrases could be okay as well I guess. The more concise the better though.

Comment: You want concise? "Thank You." or "Thanks".  If you mumble thanks, it could be even shorter.

Comment: I do not understand the sentence. Why would you thank the teacher for giving you the grade you’ve earned?  Or are you thanking them for giving you a better grade than you deserved?

Comment: It might be a matter of subjectivity. This is mostly a theoretical question.

Answer (score 1):

"Pass" is the appropriate verb:

> [pass](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pass) — to cause or permit to complete successfully (an investigation, examination, course of study, etc.): *I am passing the whole class this term.*

The example usage refers to a study who is "passing" but you can assign the cause to a teacher or professor just like your example does:

> I thanked my teacher for passing me on the exam.

This is typically used for classes or courses but it still works for individual passing grades. The opposite of "passing" is "failing":

> I thanked my teacher for failing me on the exam.

Answer (score 0):

The teacher spared you.

The teacher was clement. He showed clemency.

I once used "he let me off the hook."

Answer (score -1):

**Qualify**

> To make someone, or to become competent or eligible for some position or task.
>
> To certify or license someone for something.

so,

> I thanked the teacher for *qualifying me* in the exam.